# Excel Interop Error On Workbook Open

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I got an error when trying to open excel workbook:

```
var workbook = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
```

After that every time I've got:

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)

What is interesting, when im using Thread.Sleep(2000) before "Open" function 
everything is working correctly:

```
Thread.Sleep(2000);

var workbook = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
```

Code is running on main thread.

Any ideas what should cause that behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: If sleeping is fixing it then you probably need to show us the previous calls, like, `DoAsyncTaskThatOpensExcelButTakesASecondBeforeItsDone()`, such as `Process.Start()` (roughly, think it returns when the process exists, but that doesn't mean Excel is ready to be interacted with just yet).

Comment: How are you opening Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed that issue.

Excel workbook was opening two times and each time I was calling releaseCom method.